# MATLAB and sampling rate

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sampling

I have a question about sammpling rate in MATLAB. 
I read a `.wav` file using `audioread()`. It give me sampled data called `my_data`, and $88.2 \textrm{ kHz}$ as a samping rate, called `Fs`.

When I played this data with `audioplayer(my_data, Fs)`, it works well and totally right sounds with original file.

What I tried to do is getting odd-indexed data like this :

```
my_data = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
my_odd_data = [1 3 5 7 9]
```

I thought that this procedure is like sampling `my_data` with half of `Fs`, but it is not true. I want to know why this procedure is not sampling with `Fs/2`.

Comment: How did you verify that its not sampling with Fs/2 . from your description it looks it should work. and even I have tried it and it works

Comment: You have to use low-pass filter first. Then you can decimate your signal. Otherwise you will end up with aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said in the comments, to have it sound right you will need to low pass filter before subsampling.

The matlab function [**`decimate`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/decimate.html) does this automatically and gives some control over the type of low pass filter used.